# Corrupted external 500GB WD drive just won't mount - repairable?

Tags: backup, usb-drive, corruption

I have a corrupted USB HDD which crashes my Windows 10, if I try and open the drive in explorer. I believe I might be able to save it with linux and I tried this:

Repairing with `ntfsfix`

and this:

Installing `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils`

.. like suggested in some other threads here on the site.

All the packages seems to be doing some corrections when I run them, but I still can only see the 500 GB sda1 on my Raspian distro `lsblk` and if I try and mount it normally all hell breaks lose and I just have to pull the plug before I can get the shell to respond again. The disk just acts like crazy, sounding like it's doing something all the time, writing or something.

Anyway: Can't chkdsk it either in windows - my system just halts forever if I try and run it on the drive in CMD. Is this fixable without a new PCB and changing the bios chip from the defect one to the new PCB as I have read you can do SOME times and get the disk to mount and show files again?

Attached: picture of the drive : [image: A hard disk]

UPDATE after afreezing tthe drive - cracking uopen the window in my PC-room so the temp. was aroung 10 degrees celsius, I nervously attached the harddrive to USB. At first: no werid sounds just normal spinning up but nothing gets recognized (no partitions) as efore. BUT BEHOLD: When I enter dsikutility now in Windows it can ACTUALLY find the disk itself with unallocated data one it, ready to formatted into a new drive  - THIS IS IM PROVEMENT from before where my system would crash.

I have now immidately begun using EasyUS in the hopes that the unallocated pspace can be recovered.... just some of it at least:
[image]

Im nervously waiting on the process to finish, it says aroung 90 minutes give or take. Wish me luck - but actual kinda worked what said in the comments about freezing the drive. It kinda works now I guess. Let's see for how long.

Comment: Thought of that same thing months ago - but ALAS i found out it's a special PCB with the Mini-USB connector directly atteched to the PCB itself. So no sata connection at all to be seen and used :-(

Comment: interesting .... looking at the hard drive has loosened a bit of knowledge in my head ... lol ... here it is : freeze the drive in a freezer overnight .... in the morning, it may work long enough to retrieve your data

Comment: WHAT? Please explain in at least a psudo scientific manner how this will help? Will do it right now of corse, but why? How does it work? And Im guessing I should leave it on the radiator for an hour or so after the freeze for condensation to disappear completely?

Comment: no ... take it out of freezer and plug it in ... i have done it in the past when a drive became unmountable and i could hear the heads chattering ... i think that freezing the drive tightens up the mechanics or maybe it allows some internal circuitry to operate within some parameter ... i do not actually know

Comment: Ok interesting theory and I will try your advice, sir :) Testing it in about 6-8 hours from now - will connect the drive directly from the freezer to my Windows 10 PC and see what happens... and I will let you know the outcome here :-) Thanks so far.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want to power up a drive that's dripping condensation off it. Keep in mind that how much condensation (if any) you get on something out of the freezer depends on how humid your room is, which varies *widely* throughout the world and throughout the year.

Comment: Also... the normal advice would be to ask yourself how valuable the files on this drive are. If they're valuable, then stop doing things to the drive, and research professional data recovery. (The problem is you risk making it harder or impossible to recover).

Comment: So actually (I live in Denmark where the temp in celsius right now is about zero) - I should open up my windows and keep it freezing cold just before I connect my HDD - this way it wont condens too quickly because the temp. difference from room to HDD is much lower.. right?

Comment: They are old primary and high school files so it's just nice memories to have - not NEED to have importnat data. So am willing to try all kinds of solutions.

Comment: UPDATE UPDATE - look my latest edit and uploaded picture. IT's actually showing in diskmanager now in Windows!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a hardware issue unrelated to UNIX/Linux

Comment: It's interesting to see that you've been able to apply the freezer method, and I hope you recover your photos.

Comment: EaseUS seems to be looping from 1 hour 18 minutes to 1 hour and 15 minutes - then at starts over with the count down and never gets any lower. It found 2 uninteresting files until now - an MKV and some system file. And hoping now just to format the drive completely and at least get to use it again  a little while as a "functioning" disk".... No luck yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a rather interesting and long story short:

The RAW data partition I can see on my system on the drive is unmangeable in every way;
can't clean, can't partition, can't start recovery, use diskpart, etc., nothing helps!

I am prone to believe that at this stage, even changing the PCB and bios controller could not save it now. And I am sorry to say but: the freezer might do the trick some times, but this time I will give up... Tha data is not that important ;-)

Case closed - the data was not retrievable in an easy manner.